# When solving a second order differential equation why does one get a real sin and cosine function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading over my lecture notes for a course on differential equations and it states this:

> Consider the second order differential equation given by
>
> $L(y) = y'' +ay' +b $
>
> We can write $L = D^2+aD+bI=p(D)$
>
> So, $L(e^{mx})=p(m)e^{mx}$
>
> If $p(m)=0$ has complex roots say $m_1 = \alpha +\beta i, m_2=\alpha - \beta i$ then two complex-valued solutions to $L(y)=0$ are
>
> $e^{m_1x}=e^{\alpha x}(cos(\beta x)+isin(\beta x))$ and  $e^{m_2x}=e^{\alpha x}(cos(\beta x)-isin(\beta x))$
>
> Hence two real-valued solutions to $L(y)=0$ are $e^{\alpha x}cos(\beta x)$ and $e^{\alpha x}sin(\beta x)$

It is the final line I don't follow. The real values of $e^{m_1x}$ and $e^{m_2x}$ do not contain $sin(\beta x)$ so why is this term included for the real-valued solution for $L(y)=0$?

Comment: Note that the real parts are identical, so if you just take them you don’t get two linearly-independent solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the general solution is a linear combination of these two particular solutions, the coefficients of which *may be complex*. Hence the imaginary parts of the coefficients can compensate the $i$ in front of the sine and make it real.

E.g.

$$-i(\cos+i\sin)+i(\cos-i\sin),$$ which is real.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear homogeneous differential equation, so a linear combination of solutions is a solution.  In particular, 
$$ \eqalign{\frac{e^{m_1 x} + e^{m_2 x}}2 &= e^{\alpha x} \cos(\beta x) \cr
\frac{e^{m_1 x} - e^{m_2 x}}{2i} &= e^{\alpha x} \sin(\beta x)\cr}$$